# how to set a value for parameter of type boost::varivant <A,B>* to be equal to some A*?

Tags: c++, boost-variant

say I have

```
class A {
};
class B {
};

using AOrB = boost::variant <A,B>;

A* ptr2a = ....
AOrB* another_ptr2a = a;//this doesn't compile for me, what is the correct way to do it?
```

is using boost::variant* a bad practice?

Comment: “is using boost::variant* a bad practice?” — Almost certainly yes. Apart from that, what you want simply can’t be done: an `A*` can’t be assigned to an `A`.

Comment: `variant<A, B>*` != `variant<A*, B*>`.

Comment: `variant<A, B>` contains either an `A` or a `B`, not a `A*`. Since it is not clear though what you actually want to achieve, I am voting to close for need of clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `AOrB` is composed of either an `A` sub-object or a `B` sub-object, neither of those can point to an existing `A`, nor can a pointer to the variant type be formed from a pointer to `A`.

You can copy your `A` into an `AOrB`

```
AOrB aorb = a;
```

You can define a variant that holds either `A*` or `B*`

```
using AStarOrBStar = boost::variant<A*, B*>;
AStarOrBStar astarorbstar = &a;
```

You can apply a visitor to an `AOrB` to populate an `AStarOrBStar`

```
AStarOrBStar astarorbstar = aorb.apply_visitor([](auto & x) { return &x; });
```